# How to Merge two array of object with the same keys that have the same values and the different value will be stored in an array?

Tags: sql, node.js

I got data from database like this:

```
[
{
    id_user:1,
    expense:3000
},

{
    id_user:1,
    expense:5000
},

{
    id_user:2,
    expense:35000
},

{
    id_user:3,
    expense:50100
}
]
```

How can i convert to json like this ?

```
[
{
    id_user:1,
    expense:[3000,5000]
},

{
    id_user:2,
    expense:35000
},

{
    id_user:3,
    expense:50100
}
]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reduce & Map is way to go. And it's way better to have all expense fields to be an array, so you don't have to check weather it's an array or not

```js
const sample = [{
  id_user: 1, expense: 3000
}, {
  id_user: 1, expense: 5000
}, {
  id_user: 2, expense: 35000
}, {
  id_user: 3, expense: 50100
}]

const parseData = data => {
  return [...data.reduce((acc, { id_user, expense }) => {
    const currentUser = acc.get(id_user)
    const newExpense = currentUser ? currentUser.expense : []
    newExpense.push(expense)
    acc.set(id_user, { id_user, expense: newExpense })
    return acc
  }, new Map()).values()]
}

console.log(parseData(sample))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Max, it works and it's easy to understand

Answer (score -1):

You would just need to write a program to do it. This is how I'd approach it:

```
// phase 1
const combined = {};
for (const item of data) {
  if (!combined[item.id_user]) {
    combined[item.id_user] = [];
  }
  combined[item.id_user].push(item.expense);
}
// phase 2
const newData = [];
for (const id of Object.keys(combined)) {
  newData.push({id_user: id, expense: combined[id]});
}
```

The approach is 2 phases. The first phase goes through the data and combines `expense` values for the same user into an array. I build it into an Object since it's efficient to look up entries by their key this way. If there are a lot of records to process this will be faster than pushing into an `Array` and using `.includes` to find entries that already exist.

The 2nd phase is building the new array with the combined `expense` arrays. This is done by pushing each new object into the output `Array`.

Note that I chose to make the new `expense` always be an array even if there's only one expense. It's cleaner to have an attribute have a consistent type rather than having to check if it's an `Array` when accessing the data.